# Объединить словари

Tags: python, словари

Как объединить два словаря с выводом значений с одинаковыми ключами и с выводом None если ключ значение только одно

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}


def vmeste(a, b):
    for k, v in b.items():
        if a.get(k):
            a[k] = [a[k], v]
        else:
            a[k] = [None, v]
    return a

print(vmeste(a, b))
```

На выходе

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [None, 4], 'e': [None, 5]}
```

А хочу

```
{'a': [1, None], 'b': [2, None], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [None, 4], 'e': [None, 5]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `get` можно задать значение по умолчанию, так что тут можно просто взять `get` у обоих словарей с дефолтным значением `None`. А перебирать тут нужно объединение ключей обоих словарей. Без `sorted` почему-то порядок следования ключей получается какой-то некрасивый, пришлось дополнительно сортировать.

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

c = {k:[a.get(k, None), b.get(k, None)] for k in sorted(set(a)|set(b))}
print(c)
```

Вывод:

```
{'a': [1, None], 'b': [2, None], 'c': [3, 3], 'd': [None, 4], 'e': [None, 5]}
```